# how to fetch a table from MySQL, and display in PHP with JavaScript in an <a href=""> </a>?

Tags: php, html, mysql, webserver

I am trying to link a MySQL data table to my front end  . I have inserted directory information on the data table. If you ask, why I am doing this? I have created a multiuser login system, where an individual user is redirected to their directory. When they want to check the homepage they are taken out to the main directory index page and I want a link on the index page that they can return to their directory.

I have used the following code to do that:

I have inserted the directory information to MySQL: user-dir/user.php

when a user logged in they are being redirected to their directory 'user.php' page and if they come back to the frontend 'index.html' page, a link is been presented to them in the frontend header: the code is  the following:

```
<?PHP
$db['db_host'] ='localhost';
$db['db_user'] ='user';
$db['db_pass'] ='pass';
$db['db_name'] ='dbname';

foreach($db as $key => $value){
define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}


$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);


// Storing Session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$user_check'";
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

?>
        <li style="color: #f40707; font-size:15px; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px;" > 

                 <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['dir']; ?>"> Dashboard</a>

        </li>
```

it worked fine when a user is logged in and a session is running, but when I logout the server gives an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.exalple.com\user-dir-link\user-dir-admin.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\www.exalple.com\inc\header.php(181): require() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\www.exalple.com\login.php(32): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.exalple.com\user-dir-link\user-dir-admin.php on line 4'

Will be very helpful if anyone can help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: which line of code throws the error? It's not obvious from your sample, actually. I'm not even sure the problem line is definitely within the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

The error  shows that you are looping the entire query you should loop the results of the query. So for you to get neccessary help please provide the code where you are looping through the user info you fetched from the db

Comment: Thanks, This is the code I am using to call the user directory information (Reg-User/user-dash.php) stored in the table based on their login and username from MySQL and creating a href for them to execute on click. I am not looping anything. the code is inserted to my navbar. Is there any other way I can fetch data from the database or link user directory based on the username and id?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get exactly what you want to got but he are some of the points you might need to consider
1. To fetch user data from  database you need to loop the through the user row
2. To link the user to his info you have to create a pahe where user info is shown then when linking 
Its href =page?session =  $_SESSION ["user"], then on the page where you the profile info to appear  you have accept a  get variable which is the session and then loop through the data in the user row